# Constraints on Type Parameters for flags and |= operator

Tags: c#, .net, enums

I have enum, marked by `Flags` attribute. The enum contains the variants of the customer's chooses. In the console window user can point either the single variant, or the set of necessary variants (numbers) separated by comma. My method parses customer chooses and converts it into value of enum (set of flags).

Also I have the set of similar enums. So, I want to use the same code for set of my enums. I don't want to copy the same code, therefore I put it inside of generic method:

```
private static T GetVariants<T>() where T : struct, IConvertible 
{
    if (!typeof(T).IsEnum) {
        throw new ArgumentException("'T' must be an enumerated type.");
    }
    Dictionary<int, T> dict = new Dictionary<int, T>();
    // ...
    T cs = dict[0];
    // ...
    cs |= dict[n]; // Here is CS0019 error.
}
```

I get the compilation error:

> **Error CS0019:** Operator '|=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'T'
>   and 'T'

How can I solve it?

Comment: Would this be better as an extension method on the `Enum` type, rather than a generic method?

Comment: Totally agree with @JamesThorpe If you are restricting type of generic parameter then you should stop and think why your method should be generic

Comment: How it will help to me to restrict the `T` type as *enums*, marked by `Flags` attributes?

Comment: @AndreyBushman You won't *need to restrict*, as it will be an extension method on the enum, not a generic type `T`.

Comment: There is no way in C# to add this constraint and you cannot use the operator either. You must convert the value to a number and use normal binary OR to combine, then finally do the conversion to the enum.

Comment: What are you trying to do? ORring all the possible enum values together?

Comment: @AndreyBushman It won't, directly, but it does solve your `|=` issue.  You can then do a check for the `Flags` attribute instead of checking the type of `T`.

Comment: The same code I use for set of my enums. I don't want to copy the same code, therefore I put it inside of generic method.

Comment: Related but not a duplicate: [Is it possible to create a generic bitwise enumeration 'IsOptionSet()' method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1614412/is-it-possible-to-create-a-generic-bitwise-enumeration-isoptionset-method) The answer there should allow you to answer your own question.

Comment: @Yuval Itzchakov, but at this case parameter of that method are to have the same type (for each my flagged enum). How your way solve it problem?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're trying to do, but are you aware of [`Enum.HasFlags`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.hasflag(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: I have enum, marked by `Flags` attribute. The enum contains the variants of the customer's chooses. In the console window user can point either the single variant, or the set of necessary variants (numbers) separated by comma. My method parses customer chooses and converts it into value of enum (set of flags).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't clear what you want to obtain, BUT, using a little `Expression` tree:

```
public static class Or<T>
{
    public static readonly Func<T, T, T> Do;

    static Or()
    {
        var par1 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
        var par2 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));

        Expression or;

        if (typeof(T).IsEnum)
        {
            Type type = Enum.GetUnderlyingType(typeof(T));
            or = Expression.Convert(
                Expression.Or(
                    Expression.Convert(par1, type), 
                    Expression.Convert(par2, type)), 
                typeof(T));
        }
        else
        {
            or = Expression.Or(par1, par2);
        }

        Do = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, T, T>>(or, par1, par2).Compile();
    }
}
```

You use the code like this:

```
[Flags]
public enum MyEnum
{
    Val1 = 1,
    Val2 = 2,
    Val3 = 4,
}

public static T OrTogether<T>()
{
    T ret = default(T);

    foreach (T val in (T[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(T)))
    {
        ret = Or<T>.Do(ret, val);
    }

    return ret;
}
```